# Git merging to correct a file commit mistake

Tags: git, merge

I have some code that I've been working on and I've changed 4 files.

However during the setup process there were several files changed that I was unaware of.
Then I did a `git add .` and pull a 22 more files into the commit without realizing it.

Now 3 commits later on the branch I want to submit a merge request but I'd like to remove the 22 files that the setup changed.

I'm thinking it'd work something like this: switch back to the master branch and create a `MergeRequest` branch.

Merge the merge request branch with the work branch and cherry pick the files that I want. Is this the best way of handling this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to fix this closer to the source of the problem.  Create a branch "fix" on the commit before the problem commit.  Cherry-pick the problem commit onto that branch, committing only the files you meant to commit.  Then rebase the other commits from your branch onto fix:

git rebase --onto fix < bad commit > < original branch>

Only when things are cleaned up on your branch do you submit a merge request.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` will take to the previous state.

Use the `git reflog` command to find the SHA-1 of the previous state and then reset to it.